# Detect a kinematic rigidbody collision with a static rigidbody using Collider2D.IsTouchingLayers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a tilemap called Moving Platform and attached to it is a kinematic rigidbody (with layer mask as "Ground"). Further, there is a foreground tilemap with a layermask "Ground" (and static rigidbody) assigned to it. The scene arrangement is shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Components attached to the platform are shown below:

[image]

Components attached to the foreground are shown below:

[image]

The highlighted platform moves to right and collides with the foreground. I am trying to detect this collision in my `Update()` function, but the debug log always says false
`Debug.Log(myCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground")));`

How do I detect the collision between the two tilemaps?

If I replace the "Ground" by "Player" the collision is getting detected, since player has dynamic rigidbody attached to it. It doesn't work even if I make the platform collider a trigger collider or made the platform as dynamic rigidbody. `OnCollisionEnter2D` isn't working either.

Comment: What function i you put the code?

Comment: in update() function

Comment: That should be `myCollider.IsTouchingLayers(1<<LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));`. Let me know if that fixes the problem

Comment: No, it did not fix the problem :/

Comment: Try `myCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask(new string[] { "Ground" }))`

Comment: nope, it doesn't work either

Comment: I smell a bug. For debugging purposes, use simple BoxCollier2D or CircleCollier2D instead of CompositeCollider2D and see if that helps.

Comment: no, the box collider also doesn't work with the static foreground rigidbody

Comment: it doesn't work even if I make the collider a trigger collider or made the platform as dynamic rigidbody

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years old but I found myself having the exact same problem. The fix I found is to check the box labelled "Use Full Kinematic Collisions" on the Kinematic Rigidbody. This will allow Kinematic/Kinematic and Kinematic/Static collisions, which is what we're looking for!